# How to stretch image from placehold.co

Tags: javascript, css

For testing purposes I wanted to stretch an image.

To demonstrate there is an example:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placehold.co/500x100" />
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nkLfe86v/17)

Which gives:
[image]

My question is, why can't I stretch this image?

Comment: See if adding `object-fit: fill` for the `img` can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue

Comment: creative idea! but it doesn't seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/nkLfe86v/12/

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to strech an SVG. If you want to stretch and SVG image you can check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845452/how-to-stretch-an-svg-image. If it is just a placeholder for a `.jpg` or `.png` kind of image, you can overlook this for now.

Comment: Good catch, its an SVG. Thanks a lot!